# Replace Last Occurrence of a character in a string Using Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I am having a string like this

```
String s1 = "2999.1049.00_GRB.1";
String s2 = "my File.txt.txt";
```

I want to replace the last ".1" with "_1" and ".txt" with "_txt"

The result of the String should be

```
s1 = "2999.1049.00_GRB_1" and s2 = "my File.txt_txt"
```

How can I do this. I am aware of replacing the first occurrence of the string. but don't know how to replace the last occurrence of a string.

Comment: Use lastIndexOf?

Comment: This question doesn't demonstrate a whole lot of research on your part.

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: You can use
`System.out.println("***"+s1.substring(0,s1.lastIndexOf(".")) +"_"+s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf(".")+1));`

It will work for both`s1` and `s2`

Comment: One more answer `class abc
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String s1= "2999.1049.00_GRB.1";
        int i=s1.lastIndexOf(".");
        StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(s1);
        myName.setCharAt(i, '_');
        System.out.println(myName);
        
    }
}`   By using `lastIndexOf` `.`  and `replace` this index by `_` using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thank You @Rohit-Pandey. I got my solution

Answer (score 1):

Simply use .replace with lastIndexOf method of string

```
System.out.println(s.replace(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(".1"), s.length()), "_1"));
```

Comment: it assumes it's always ".1"

Comment: I have no idea how this `.1` appeared here, and tbh I'm quite curious x)

Comment: As per his need he  require always ".1" else can be defined a variable to make it dynamic.

Comment: You want to change the answer to say "." and "_" for example.

Comment: @GhostCat: It should be as you are suggesting. Then it will be like :System.out.println(s.replace(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(".")-1, s.length()-1), "_"));

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex :

```
s = s.replaceAll("(.*)\\.(\\d+)$","$1_$2");  

//  (everything)point(digits) -> (everything)underscore(digits)
```

It will capture all element before the `.` in a group (`group1`), the digit(s) after in another group (`group2`), and replace by : `group1_group2`

- the first group can be whatever you want
- the second group is just digits, even more than 1

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/rUV0kM/1)